# How to bind multiple nested properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Here is my problem, I have the following data structure:

```
public class Job : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public StateEnum State {
        get { return this.state; }

        private set {
            this.state = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    public List<Job> Jobs {
        get { return this.jobs; }

        private set {
            this.jobs = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display a global state summary of the jobs in the main window.

I first tried to make a data binding on the Jobs list, then use a custom IValueConverter to display the global state. Problem: It is not refreshed when the job states change (since it is bind to the collection and not the states).

```
ProgressState="{Binding Jobs, Converter={StaticResource JobsToProgressState}, ElementName=MainWindow}"
```

So I was trying to find a solution where I can bind all the nested properties of the jobs to a IMultiValueConverter. I did not find any syntax to make this work.

Is it possible to do something like that?

EDIT: 
I want to do something like

```
ProgressState="{Binding Jobs[*].State, Converter={StaticResource JobsToProgressState}, ElementName=MainWindow}"
```

And retrieve an array containing all job states (*StateEnum[]*) in the JobsToProgressState converter.

Comment: State and Jobs are fields, not properties. Data binding works with public properties only. Please post the relevant parts of your exact code here to avoid confusion.

Comment: As @Clemens mentioned that you have to define the field as property, also, you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: Sorry, I will make it explicit in my sample. But these are public DependencyProperties.

Comment: If Jobs collection is changing then you should implement as `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`

Comment: The job collection is not changing. The state of the jobs are changing.

Comment: @Tichau then why call `OnPropertyChanged` on `Jobs` in the first place? `ObservableCollection` already implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: @Pulle you're right, I will change this list for an observableCollection so it will be more readable (and will allow me to add or remove jobs in the futur). Do you think it will 
fix my issue?

Comment: @Tichau it won't, the problem is that `OnPropertyChanged` is not thrown when a record of an `IList` changes. You need to throw the `OnPropertyChanged` of the `Job` up to your `Job` List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `OnPropertyChanged` is not fired when a record of an `IList` changes. You need to delegate the `OnPropertyChanged` of the `Job` up to your `Jobs`-List.

This rough implementation will do what you want.

```
public class Job : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    public StateEnum State {
        get { return this.state; }

        private set {
            this.state = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    public List<Job> Jobs {
        get { return this.jobs; }

        private set {
            this.jobs = value;

            foreach(var job in this.jobs)
            {
                job.PropertyChanged += job_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void job_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Jobs");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to unwire your event registrations when you don't need them any more.

Comment: Neither a method nor an event is "thrown". A method is called, and an event is raised (or sometimes fired).